# Why there is no octal code number 3 for granting file permissions?

Tags: file, permissions, octal

Permissions may be granted to users and groups using octal codes:

```
Read access - 4
Write (change) permission - 2
Execute script of binary executable - 1
Read and Execute - 5
Read and Write - 6
Read, Write and Execute - 7
```

Why there's no octal code 3? Perhaps it once existed and was deprecated? If so, what was its ancient usage?

If it never existed, why they skipped it? Was it a way to force the use of the cabalistic number 7? Are the people behind the creation of group access hiding something away from us? Who were these people anyway?  Were they some kind of druids or were they serious computer scientists? Why would they omit the number? What if I chmod 333 a file? What if the file comes...ALIVE?!

Answer (score 0):

3 would be the permission to write and execute, but without the permission to read.  That makes no sense, hu?!

Edit (29.05.15):
With the addition of the 3 basic values (1,2 and 4) you will get an unique value.

```
    1 + 2 = 3
    1 + 4 = 5
    2 + 4 = 6
1 + 2 + 4 = 7
```

So every basic and calculated value is unique.

If you use 3 as a basic value, you can't really know if it is the basic value or the calculated one (1 + 2).

Comment: But why skip number 3?